# ¿Por qué decimos "me da palo" cuando algo nos da pereza?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, modismos, expresiones, españa

Se oye con frecuencia en España:

> - Mañana tengo que ir a trabajar. ¡**Qué palo me da**!

o

> - Esta noche tengo cena de familiar. **Me da un palo horrible**, el pesado de mi cuñado siempre está con sus chistecitos.

Es decir, se usa **dar palo** (más, opcionalmente, algún calificativo) para indicar que algo nos da pereza, nos asquea.

El DRAE menciona la expresión, pero le da un significado bastante diferente:

> **[palo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RaOp0rz)**
>
> (...)
>
> dar palo
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Salir o suceder algo al contrario de como se esperaba o deseaba.

Entonces me pregunto: ¿de dónde viene esta expresión?

Añado: leo en [WordReference - me da palo](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/me-da-palo.296657/?hl=es) que en Canarias tiene otro significado:

> En Canarias cuando se usa la expresión "me da palo" se hace con el
>   significado de "dar vergüenza", no tiene ninguna otra acepción aquí.

Por lo que la siguiente pregunta es obligada: ¿Dónde más se usa esta expresión con este significado? ¿Qué quiere decir en otras regiones?

Comment: Yo la verdad es que nunca le había dado a la expresión el sentido que mencionas. Por mi propia experiencia, yo siempre la he usado tal y como indica la RAE y como se usa en Canarias. En ese sentido, también decimos _me da corte_. RAE: dar corte algo a alguien. _loc. verb. coloq. Darle vergüenza, apuro, etc._

Comment: Leyendo con más detenimiento el enlace a WordReference veo que a poca gente le suena así y que suele ser la de la zona de Cataluña. En catalán tenemos la expresión _em dóna pal_ ("me da palo"), así que podría ser que el castellano de esta región la absorbiera.

Comment: En Chile no se usa. En cambio decimos _me da paja ir a clases_, entendiendo "paja" como masturbación (y, por supuesto, asociando la falta de ganas de trabajar con el gasto energético que conlleva masturbarse). La expresión es coloquial, pero curiosamente no es tan grosera como podría esperarse. Hay otros derivados como _ando con paja_ y _no seai pajero_. La paja y el palo son tallos, se podría hacer la analogía, pero no, el origen de [paja](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?paja) es bien claro y no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: @Rodrigo En España es muy usada la palabra _paja_ para referirse a la masturbación. En nuestro caso, es bastante vulgar. Lo de _dar paja_ no lo tenemos. Por cierto, me parece curiosísima la asociación que comentas de las ganas de trabajar con el gasto energético de la masturbación. Creo que daría para una pregunta, me lo apunto :)

Comment: Solo la he oido en el sentido de "dar vergüenza" (España - Madrid, Soria, Burgos)

Comment: ¿Y no podría venir derivada de otra expresión como "no dar ni un palo al agua" que también se refiere a la pereza?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal y como lo menciona el DRAE, creo que el sentido es bastante literal: cuando algo no sale como esperas *te llevas un palo*, es decir, es como si te dieran con un palo para devolverte a la realidad. No puedo afirmarlo categóricamente, pero seguramente vendrá de los castigos físicos, cuando hacías algo mal y te pillaban te podían arrear desde con el cinturón hasta con una vara. Por tanto, si algo no salía como esperabas y te pillaban te llevabas un palo, pero físicamente. Hoy en día se usa más metafóricamente (menos mal).

Ahora bien, cómo pasó la expresión a significar `dar pereza`, lo ignoro. Imagino que si sabes que por hacer algo te puedes llevar un castigo empiezas a dejar de querer hacerlo. Por tanto, no sería raro decir que algo *te da palo* cuando sencillamente no tienes ganas o voluntad de hacerlo.

Comment: Curiosamente la palabra "trabajo" viene del latín _tripalium_, los "tres palos" en los que se amarraba a los esclavos para azotarlos. O sea, trabajo=castigo. (+1, aunque yo tampoco me imagino cómo llegó a significar pereza).

Answer (score 2):

Desde luego cuando nos llevamos un palo, algo sale de forma contraria a como esperábamos, pero hay que matizar esa definición del DRAE con **es para mal**. No te *llevas un palo* si pensabas suspender el examen de física y luego resulta que apruebas. Y desde luego entendemos que el "palo" es algo malo por la asociación con el dolor físico:

> Vaya palo, he vuelto a suspender matemáticas.
>
> El mecánico me ha dado un *palo* de 300 euros por arreglarme el coche.

La evolución a "me da vergüenza" es por el sentido de "es una humillación tan grande que (casi) me causa dolor físico" aunque el dolor en este caso puede ser "emocional".

> Me gusta esa chica, pero me da palo (vergüenza) pedirle salir. No quiero llevarme un palo (estar en una situación amarga, violenta, en evidencia) si me dice que no.
>
> Lo compré porque el vendedor insistía tanto que me dio palo decirle que no. No quería que la gente pensase mal de mi.

La evolución a "me da pereza" llega por motivos similares. Tengamos en cuenta que son solo usamos la expresión *llevarse un palo* sino que también usamos el término `paliza`.

> Estoy cansadísimo. Me he dado una paliza a limpiar este finde: las ventanas, los baños... toda la casa!
>
> Vaya paliza de libro. No hay quién se lo termine. Es muy aburrido!

Del [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RZ5d5F4):

> 1. f. Serie de golpes dados con un palo o con cualquier otro medio o instrumento.
> 2. f. Esfuerzo que produce agotamiento.

Dicho esto, la asociación entre "dar palo" y "cansancio" está más clara. Es un uso como hiperbólico del estilo "me cansa tanto que me duele" o "me deja tan cansado como si me hubiesen *dado de palos* (una paliza).

> Mis amigas querían que fuera de copas con ellas, pero es que **me daba palo** tener que ducharme, maquillarme e ir hasta tan lejos con el frío que hace. Mejor me quedo en casa viendo una serie. Qué **paliza** ser mujer y tener que estar siempre con el maquillaje!